# Bootstrap 4.3.1 - Navbar won't collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It seems the bootstrap is not working. The navbar wont collapse and the toggle button not appearing when you Minimize? But if I'm not mistaken I have used this exact code before and I think it worked; but I went to an application I wrote before to see if it will still work so I can just copy from there and it didn't work also. Its navbar which I know collapsed the time I wrote it didn't collapse again. please help me Sir/Ma...here is the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJidb.jpg)

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the code in a text format so we can replicate it. The version of bootstrap imported and code used might be different causing this ig

Comment: Okay will do that

Comment: with respect to the question Heres the code below:                                                     
             <div class="container"><nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark"><a class="navbar-brand" asp-action="index" asp-controller="home">
                <img src="~/images/imagese.png" height="30" width="30" /></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>           </button>div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

Comment: I used Bootstrap 4.3.1